# IIS Error Logging. No error message

Tags: .net, iis, web

I have started to deploy a website on IIS and for some reason I am getting an error when I am trying to access logging.

The exact error message is:
"There was an error while performing this operation.
Detais:
Filename: \?\E:\inetpub\wwwroot\websitename\web.config
Error:"

Very helpful! I also validated my xml, two out of three validators said there was no error and the third said there was: "Can not find declaration of element 'configuration'." Which confused me further. Has anyone else had trouble with the IIS Logging?

EDIT: I have just tried navigating to some of the other features and I am getting the same message as the above.

EDIT 2: Apologies for the lateness in me adding the config. I hope this is sufficient I removed everything that I thought might be not acceptable to share.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <section name="Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>

    <!-- Add new Enterprise Library Config Sections-->

    <section name="RetryPolicyConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.TransientFaultHandling.Configuration.RetryPolicyConfigurationSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.TransientFaultHandling.Configuration" />

    <sectionGroup name="elmah">
      <section name="security" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorMail" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorFilter" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler, Elmah" />
    </sectionGroup>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>



  <appSettings>
    <!-- TST -->
    <!--Shared-->
    <add key="SmtpServer" value="" />
    <add key="MobileDataCaptureConnectionString" value="Data Source=tcp;Initial Catalog=;Integrated Security=True;" />
    <add key="LogMemoryUsage" value="True" />
    <add key="EmailFrom" value="" />
    <add key="QAManagerEmail" value="" />
    <add key="EmailSuppliers" value="True" />
    <add key="EmailGroupAuditFail" value="" />
    <add key="EmailGroupWharfAuditFail" value="" />
    <add key="EmailFailedCreatingPDF" value="" />
    <add key="ReportDestination" value="" />
    <add key="ReportPath" value="/Quality/PDA Audit/Audit Findings and Outcomes" />
    <add key="CanopyLink" value="" />
    <add key="SmtpFrom" value="" />
    <add key="ReportService2005Url" value="" />
    <add key="ReportExecution2005Url" value="" />
    <add key="CanopyLink_PINs" value="" />
    <add key="InfoPathXsdSchema" value="" />
    <add key="InfoPathAuditXmlNamespace" value="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2010-10-28T21:55:39" />
    <!-- Sends email notifications to DebugEmailAddress when it is specified. When deploying to prod, clear out the value-->
    <add key="DebugEmailAddress" value="" />
    <add key="ADUserDetailsService" value="" />
  </appSettings>
  <applicationSettings />
  <connectionStrings>
    <!--Mobile Data Capture-->
    <add name="MobileDataCapture" connectionString="Data Source=tcp:;Initial Catalog=Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="Web.MobileQA.Properties.Settings.MobileDataCaptureConnectionString" connectionString=";Initial Catalog=;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="Web.MobileQA.BL.Properties.Settings.MobileDataCaptureConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=tcp:;Initial Catalog=;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <!-- Agg First Login Service -->
    <add name="NotionIntegrationConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=tcp:;Initial Catalog=;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="CropProtectionConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=tcp:;Initial Catalog=;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <!-- Retry Policies-->
  <RetryPolicyConfiguration defaultRetryStrategy="Fixed Interval Retry Strategy" defaultSqlConnectionRetryStrategy="Backoff Retry Strategy" defaultSqlCommandRetryStrategy="Incremental Retry Strategy" defaultAzureStorageRetryStrategy="Fixed Interval Retry Strategy" defaultAzureServiceBusRetryStrategy="Fixed Interval Retry Strategy">
    <!-- retryInterval="00:00:01" -->
    <incremental name="Incremental Retry Strategy" initialInterval="00:00:01" retryIncrement="00:00:01" maxRetryCount="10" />
    <fixedInterval name="Fixed Interval Retry Strategy" retryInterval="00:00:01" maxRetryCount="10" />
    <exponentialBackoff name="Backoff Retry Strategy" minBackoff="00:00:01" maxBackoff="00:00:30" deltaBackoff="00:00:10" maxRetryCount="10" firstFastRetry="false" />

    <incremental name="WebServiceClientRetryPolicy" initialInterval="00:00:01" retryIncrement="00:00:01" maxRetryCount="10" />
    <incremental name="FileStorageRetryPolicy" initialInterval="00:00:01" retryIncrement="00:00:01" maxRetryCount="10" />
    <incremental name="TransactionRetryPolicy" initialInterval="00:00:01" retryIncrement="00:00:01" maxRetryCount="10" />
  </RetryPolicyConfiguration>


  <system.web>
    <webServices>
      <!-- enable remote testing-->
      <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet" />
        <add name="HttpPost" />
      </protocols>
    </webServices>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5" />
    <identity impersonate="false" />
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID" />
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" />
      <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" />
      <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" />
    </httpModules>
    <sessionState mode="Off" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules>
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^.asmx*" ignoreCase="true" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>    
  </system.webServer>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="ErrorLogSoap" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="AgentSoap" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ErrorLogSoap" contract="ErrorService.ErrorLogSoap" name="ErrorLogSoap" />
      <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="AgentSoap" contract="UpdateService.AgentSoap" name="AgentSoap" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true" />
    <sources>
      <source name="System.Web.Services.Asmx">
        <listeners>
          <add name="AsmxTraceFile" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="local.log" traceOutputOptions="LogicalOperationStack, DateTime, Timestamp, ProcessId, ThreadId" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <switches>
      <add name="System.Web.Services.Asmx" value="Verbose" />
    </switches>
  </system.diagnostics>

  <elmah>
    <security allowRemoteAccess="false" />
    <errorLog applicationName="MobileQA" type="Common.Cloud.ElmahRedisStorage.RedisStorageErrorLog,Common.Cloud.ElmahRedisStorage" connectionString="cchzesdnttstuswe01.redis.cache.windows.net:6380,Ssl=true,ConnectRetry=3,ConnectTimeout=2000,SyncTimeout=2000,KeepAlive=300" maxErrors="200" environment="TST" />
  </elmah>

  <location path="elmah.axd" inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.web>
      <httpHandlers>
        <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
      </httpHandlers>
    </system.web>

    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="ELMAH" verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      </handlers>      
    </system.webServer>

  </location>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: post your web.config file

Comment: stripping out the sensitive bits of course  ;)

Comment: Sorry for taking so long, I stopped trying to troubleshoot the dev environment and started working on the tst environment (because tst was still working as a webservice)